# What is the difference Job.Cancel vs Scope.Cancel in coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have been exploring coroutines and I am quite surprised to see that cancel called on Job does not actually cancel the job while cancel called on scope cancels the coroutines launched from the scope immediately. Can anyone explain this?

Job cancel example.

```
/**
     * This never stops
     */
    @Test
    fun coroutineTest7() = runBlocking {
        val job = launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            var count = 0
            while(true){
                if(isActive){
                    println("Hello ${count++}")
                }
                else {
                    println("Job Cancelled but this will still get printed")
                }
                Thread.sleep(500)
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(6000)
        job.cancel()
        Unit
    }
```

Scope cancel example

```
/**
     * This gets cancelled after six seconds
     */
    @Test
    fun coroutineTest5() = runBlocking {
        val newScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
        newScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            var count = 0
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(500)
                println("Hello ${count++}")
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(6000)
        newScope.cancel()
        Unit
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first code block, your Job does not cooperate with cancellation. It has an infinite loop and does not call any suspend functions that cooperate with cancellation, so there is no way to exit the loop or for the Job to be cancelled. Since `runBlocking` runs for as long as its child coroutines are running, it waits forever for the Job to be complete.

In your second code block, your Job still doesn't cooperate with cancellation, but since it's launched in a different CoroutineScope instead of `runBlocking`'s scope, `runBlocking` doesn't wait for the Job to finish. So although your Job is running forever, `runBlocking` will promptly return after the `newScope.cancel()` call, thereby freeing your app process to exit and cutting the misbehaving coroutine short. I suspect if you had other long-running tests in this Unit test suite, you may continue to see that job logging during other tests until the process exits.

You can modify the second test to continue waiting after the `runBlocking` to see that the Job is still continuing to run in the background:

```
@Test
fun coroutineTest5() {
    runBlocking {
        val newScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
        newScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            var count = 0
            while(true){
                Thread.sleep(500)
                println("Hello ${count++}")
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(6000)
        newScope.cancel()
        println("Cancelled scope")
        Thread.sleep(2000)
    }
    println("Run blocking returned")
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    println("Returning from test")
}
```

Comment: I see. So the runBlocking waits for child coroutines to complete, but does not wait for coroutines scope declared inside of it get completed. That makes sense. Regarding the logs continuing to print in the second case, i wanted to prove it somehow. How do i simulate a long running test?

Comment: See my update for a way to prove it from within the same test. But you can add additional tests to your suite that come after this one and have them take more than 500ms.